# How to determine the right strategy for WFS requests with Getotools?

Tags: wfs, java, geotools

I found that the strategy is selected in the `determineCorrectStrategy()` method in [`org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSClient`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/wfs-ng/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/wfs/internal/WFSClient.java).

I don't know how reliable the suggestions are for all the strategies but e.g. for mapserver I found multiple services that do not contain "mapserver" or "map=" but something like "mapserv" and are therefore not found if the strategy is set to "auto" (default).

Are there more reliable indicators to choose the right strategy?

Comment: Not really. All WFS servers should look and behave alike but in real life that is not quite true. You could add to the list that if WFS is using namespace ms: it is perhaps a MapServer. However, the namespace is not necessarily the default one as well as URL does not need to contain cci-bin, mapserv, mapserver, &map= etc.

Comment: The assumption is that the user should know and set the strategy. auto is just a set of heuristics that might help. http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/procedures/contribute.html

Comment: Unfortunately this assumption is not met in my case. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: None of our umn mapserver services reference the map file in the URL, or use mapserv.  The presence of the word mapserver in a URL often indicates an ArcGIS service.  Trying to determine what software is providing a service through its URL is a flawed approach.